# Derby NATIVE authentication user creation

Tags: java, database, derby

I create DB with `NATIVE authentication`. When i create user with temporary password, users can't login to DB with their temporary passwords. Here is my code;

**Creating User;**

```
String uName = userNameTextField.getText();
String pass = new String (passTextField.getPassword());

stmt2.execute("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_CREATE_USER('"+"\""+uName+"\""+"', '"+"\""+pass+"\""+"')");
```

**Connection Attempt;**

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:derby://10.90.232.2:1527/myDB"+";create=false;" + "user=" +"\""+ unameTextField.getText() +"\""+ ";" + "password=" +"\""+ new String (passwordPasswordField.getPassword()) +"\""+ ";"; 
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
```

**SQLException;**

```
ERROR 08004: DERBY SQL error: ERRORCODE: 40000, SQLSTATE: 08004, SQLERRMC: Database connection refused.
```

If i try create same user, derby turn `username already exist` error. So this is show me actually user creation is done. But i don't understand why password not accepted.

**--EDIT--**

Also i have checked `SYS.SYSUSERS` System Table which stores `NATIVE` users. I see created user in there.

**QUERY;**

```
String query = "select USERNAME,HASHINGSCHEME,LASTMODIFIED from SYS.SYSUSERS";
stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();  
int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();

while (rs.next()) {
   for (int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber; i++) {
      if (i > 1) System.out.print(",  ");
      String columnValue = rs.getString(i);
      System.out.print(columnValue);
   }
   System.out.println("");
}
```

**OUTPUT;**

```
owner,  3b62:53f094d5ab95f45fd351aca5856e0c06:1000:SHA-256,  2016-01-03 10:41:45.008
testuser,  3b62:bb98971e23c129fcd6e4cef37e9ac01d:1000:SHA-256,  2016-01-03 10:55:10.969
```

**P.S.:** Also `SYS.SYSUSERS` System table has `PASSWORD` Column. But when we try fetch it in query, derby turns `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: No one can view the 'SYSUSERS'.'PASSWORD' column.` exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**--SOLVED--**

If Database created with;

```
s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
                "'derby.database.defaultConnectionMode', 'noAccess')");
```

Users permissions overriden. And they can't login to system. It must be `fullAccess`.

And we must specified;

```
s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
                "'derby.connection.requireAuthentication', 'true')");

s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
                "'derby.database.sqlAuthorization', 'true')");
```

For restrict reach to system `unauthenticated` and `unauthorized` users. We can use `GRANT` and `REVOKE` for which users can reach which database objects.

Comment: I'm glad you figured this out! If you can see a way to describe how to improve the documentation for this feature, I'm sure the Derby devs would appreciate the contribution.

Comment: Actually derby documentation say it. `DATABASE_PROPERTY always override the user permission` But i forgot where i am reading it. If i remember the link i will share.

Comment: Here is the link: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.6/devguide/cdevcsecure36595.html `The access mode specified for the derby.database.defaultConnectionMode property overrides the permissions that are granted by the owner of a database object. For example, if a user is granted INSERT privileges on a table but the user only has read-only connection authorization, the user cannot insert data into the table.` Actually Derby talk about user priviliges not connect to system i think. Is it a bug do you think or planned thing?